# How to shedule action on post_save?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have function called on post_save:

```
def my_func():
    ...
```

and handler:

```
signals.post_save.connect(my_func, sender=Model)
```

How to sheduled this call to end of the day (eta = datetime.combine(date.today(), time.max))?

Comment: You want the post_save method to schedule your task at the end of the day or do you want to run my_func at the end of the day regardless? Whichever case, you'll probably need something like Celery (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Celery can be used if u want to run them too often. If only end of the day use cron